# GSON JSON Mapping

Tags: java, json, gson

Please I need help about to pull my hair out.

Using GSON to read JSON input returned from my PHP web service.

simplified (test) JSON looks like:

> {"Posts":[{"post":{"Areaid":"1"}},{"post":{"Areaid":"2"}}]}

Code look like this:

```
 public void viewAreas() throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, Area>> map=viewAreaResponseToMap("{\"Posts\":[{\"post\":{\"Areaid\":\"1\"}},{\"post\":{\"Areaid\":\"2\"}}]}");

        for (Map<String, Area> map1 : map) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Area> entry : map1.entrySet()) {
                String string = entry.getKey();
                System.out.println(string);
                Area list = entry.getValue();
                    System.out.println(list.Areaid);
            }
        }
    }

    private List<Map<String, Area>> viewAreaResponseToMap(String response) throws Exception {
        List<Map<String, Area>> map = new Gson().fromJson(response, new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Area>>>() {
        }.getType());

        return map;
    }
```

with the Area class like:

```
public class Area {
    public String Areaid;
}
```

However when I call `viewAreas()` I get:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2

I have tried many different ways i.e `Map<String,List<Area>>`, `List<Map<String,List<Area>>>` but I just cant seem to map the JSON response correctly.

Any help or advice?

Comment: Could it be `Map<String,List<Map<String,Area>>` ?

Comment: @herman Thank you so much please put it as an answer and I will accept btw you are missing a >

Comment: Or you could change the json to `[{"post":{"Areaid":"1"}},{"post":{"Areaid":"2"}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that should be `Map<String,List<Map<String,Area>>>`, but I've never used GSON before :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp - Not really a guess.  Look at your structure.  The outermost containing characters are `[]` which is a JSON "array" => Java List.  The `{}` characters are a JSON "object" => Java Map.  It's blazingly simple.  See json.org.

Comment: @HotLicks lol first time getting to grips with JSON. Thanks I will have a look at it to get my head around that

Comment: @DavidKroukamp - I don't understand why folks have so much trouble with JSON, since it's so incredibly simple.  (Though Java folks do muck it up quite a bit with generics and stuff like Jackson.)